# Symfony crawler - how to analyse nodes?

Tags: symfony

Here is what I have:

```
    $nodeValues = $crawler->filter("#as-responses-table > tr > td")->each(function ($node) {
        // What do I do here?
    });
```

What I want to do is analyse each `<td>` - that means I want to be able to read the attributes. I want to read the value of td (ie. what is between the tags).

How on earth do I do this?

Each `$node` is a Crawler, I want to be able to look at the HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read node attributes

```
$attribute = $node->attr('attribute_name');
```

To get the node content

```
$content = $node->text();
```

http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html